# designing android app backend

Tags: java, android, go, backend

If I need to design an entire android app and host my app on google play, and my users need to get real-time data, how would I go about designing the backend.

I learnt few things about views, view groups, layouts, event listeners in java, programming in latest android studio. But I'm just in the learning phase.

Is there any other better IDE. Can we program in atom, does it has any package that can emulate android phones.

Mainly I'm concerned about the DB choice, frontend-backend communication. Is there any service which is open source for hosting in the cloud that has a great uptime and supporting easy scaling. Of course, I can google each and everything, but those will be on different perspectives. I just wanted some answer which is tailor made and easy to understand.

Answer (score 3):

This question could definitely result in a myriad of answers and approaches. But, in terms of something straightforward to maintain (considering you have Go tagged in the question) I would recommend checking out the following:

For using Go, I have found [Echo](https://echo.labstack.com/) to be a pretty awesome framework to bootstrap Go web services. It offers a very flexible and performant router that uses a middleware design pattern, as well as a lot of other nice features.

For hosting and maintaining your web services, you should look into using [Heroku](https://dashboard.heroku.com/). They have a pretty amazing platform that officially supports Go deployments. You can start for free, and then scale up your services pretty effortlessly. They also offer myriad of third party integrations for monitoring, logging, emails, sms, and databases.

In terms of databases, that one can't be answered really without a significant amount of knowledge around what you are doing with your data - but using Heroku, you can spin up a PostGres SQL instance, MongoDB, and Redis for free. For what you are doing it sounds like a combination of the above might be useful for your needs.

In terms of Android development - I have not found anything better than Android Studio. It's free, provides all the emulators you could ever need, and in general all the features you would want out of an IDE to do Android right, plus it is maintained by Google.

Good luck!